# scrolls bar hidden but one show

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where scrolling has been completely disabled using this css style.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

But now I need a specific scroll inside a div (horizontal scroll) to be visible. How could I show only one scroll while hiding all the others.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to outright disable scrolling? Have you thought about the accessibility implications of doing that? Not everyone has mice with scrollwheels or multi-touch touchpads - and users can force scrolling by dragging a selection too.

Comment: It is a requirement of the project.

Comment: Unless this is a school project then you can always push-back against unreasonable requirements - and I'd ignore any client that asked me to do something like that without a very good reason. But as I said, simply hiding the scrollbar doesn't stop users from scrolling the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: You can use your class/id name to replace body Than use display block

Comment: but if I put this all the scrollbars appears?

Comment: No. Use your specific class name where you want this

Answer (score 0):

try instead of hiding all the scrollbars hide same of them

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.ele-2::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="ele-1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddd</div>

<div class="ele-2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddd</div>
```